# Changing audio bit rate after recording

Tags: ios, audio, compression, core-audio

I'm recording audio files at a bit rate of 44.1khz.  I like having high quality audio for playback purposes.  However, when I want to export via text or email, the audio files fail to export because they're larger than 15MB (usually for audio files +3mins).  Is there a way to reduce the bit rate only when I want to export?  I've seen the following tutorial, but I'd rather keep my files as m4a rather than converting to aac: 
http://atastypixel.com/blog/easy-aac-compressed-audio-conversion-on-ios/.

Comment: M4A normally indicates an MPEG-4 Audio file container.  The file can contain Apple Lossless or AAC encoded audio.  What codec do you want to use?

Comment: @sbooth I'm not sure as I'm new to the subject.  My reasoning for sending files that are m4a is for the playback capability.  I can text someone an m4a and they could open and play it easily.  With AAC, I believe the compressed audio has to be uncompressed.  Is this true?

Comment: you mentioned 44.1 kHz - (sample rate) which indicates how often audio is measured (sampled) per second - it is one of two components of bit rate - the other component is bit depth which indicates the resolution in bits at which each sample is recorded - to change bit rate you can alter either/both of these underlying measurements :  bit rate == (sample rate) * (bit depth)

Comment: @ScottStensland got it.  If I want to reduce the size of the audio file after it has been recorded, how can I reduce the number the number of bits?  Sample rate and bit depth can't be changed after recording, right?

Comment: To change the codec parameters in any way you'll first have to decompress the audio from whatever format it's in to PCM for the encoder.  What are your requirements for audio quality? File size? What level of Core Audio are you working with?

Comment: sure you can reduce bit rate at any time - before/during/after recording, its lossy so will lower audible fidelity based on how much you alter it - its also a balancing act, to minimize fidelity loss you simultaneously drop both sample rate and bit depth

Comment: @sbooth I don't have any requirements for quality and file size when exporting files.  As long as the audio file is less than 15MB it will send, but I'd prefer the size to be much smaller so I can export multiple files.  I also don't want the audio quality to be horribly low.  I'm doing all of this in AVFoundation.

Comment: @ScottStensland thanks for the info.  So how does one go about reducing the bit rate after recording, while balancing both bit depth and and sample rate?

Comment: sample rate 44.1 kHz is the CD standard however 8 kHz is intelligible  and may be configurable from iOS - also drop down to mono - these two steps will take your 15MB stereo down to just over one meg - there are command line tools like avconv and ffmpeg which do such transforms so U can hear results now before writing any code ... avconv -i someStereofile.wav -ac 1 -ar 8000 output_mono_8_kHz.wav

Comment: @ScottStensland I don't really understand the syntax at the very of your last line.  I tried looking up avconv but couldn't find anything in the developers library.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AVAssetReader and AVAssetWriter to transcode an audio file to one with different parameters (lower bit rate, higher compression, etc.).  Just because you create a new (temporary?) audio file for export doesn't force you to delete the current higher quality audio file you want for playback.